# Get Sequential Number using ROW_NUMBER function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get a Sequential Number using the ROW_NUMBER function? I need the following type of result. RN as 1,1 for first 2 rows 2,2 for next 2 rows and so on.

```
CREATE TABLE DateType
(      
    id int,
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO DateType VALUES (1, '1-1-2020', '1-1-2021')
INSERT INTO DateType VALUES (2, '1-1-2017', '1-1-2019')
INSERT INTO DateType VALUES (3, '1-1-2016', '1-1-2018')
INSERT INTO DateType VALUES (4, '1-1-2014', '1-1-2015')
INSERT INTO DateType VALUES (5, '1-1-2012', '1-1-2013')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not spam the `tag`. Choose only the tag for the database that you are using. Also please avoid posting image and post it as text

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Looks like MS SQL Server, @jarlh, according to screenshot which says "IDEAPAD (**SQL Server** 15.0.2080.9 ...)".

Comment: Sample data *and* expected results will help us help you

Answer (score 0):

> I need the following type of result. RN as 1,1 for first 2 rows 2,2 for next 2 rows and so on.

You can use arithmetic:

```
select dt.*,
       ceiling(row_number() over (order by id) / 2.0) as pair_number
from DateType dt;
```

Note that in your sample data, `id` starts at 1 and has no gaps.  If this is true in your data, you don't need `row_number()` at all:

```
select dt.*,
       ceiling(id / 2.0) as pair_number
from DateType dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

[dbo.fnTally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally) is good for this type of thing.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE = '1-1-2012', 
        @enddate   DATE = '1-1-2021';

SELECT RN        = DATEDIFF(YEAR,@startdate,@enddate)/2-t.N+1,
       StartDate = DATEADD(YEAR,t.N*2,@startdate),
       EndDate   = DATEADD(YEAR,t.N*2+1,@startdate)
FROM     dbo.fntally(0,DATEDIFF(YEAR,@startdate,@enddate)/2) AS t
ORDER BY t.N DESC;
```

**Results:**

```
RN   StartDate  EndDate
---- ---------- ----------
1    2020-01-01 2021-01-01
2    2018-01-01 2019-01-01
3    2016-01-01 2017-01-01
4    2014-01-01 2015-01-01
5    2012-01-01 2013-01-01
```